# How do you compute $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos(x))\tan^{-1}(\cot(x))}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried using the identity of $\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ and doing substitutions like $u=\cos(x)$, but I keep ending up with $0$.
Is there a concept I'm missing?

Comment: Hint: the behaviour of $\sqrt{(\pi/2-x)^2}$ is a bit different on $x\in(\pi/2,\,\pi]$. You'll find your integral is the area of a triangle.

Comment: \begin{align}
I=&\ 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos x)\tan^{-1}(\cot x)}\ dx
=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{(\frac\pi2-x)^2}\ dx=\frac{\pi^2}4
\end{align}

Comment: Got it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos(x))\tan^{-1}(\cot(x))}dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)^2} dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left|\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right| dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) ~dx + \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \left(x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) ~dx$$
$$= \left[\frac{\pi}{2}x - \frac{1}{2}x^2\right]_0^{\pi/2} + \left[\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{\pi}{2}x \right]_{\pi/2}^{\pi}$$
$$=\left(\frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{8}\right) + \left(\frac{\pi^2}{2} - \frac{\pi^2}{2}\right) - \left( \frac{\pi^2}{8} - \frac{\pi^2}{4} \right)$$
$$=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

If you're getting 0, you may have forgotten the absolute value in going from $\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)^2}$ to $\left|\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right|$.

Answer (score 2):

If you graph this function, you get [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/suwkuw0utm). Use the area of a triangle formula to get your answer $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=definite+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22variable%22%7D+-%3E%22x%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22rangestart%22%7D+-%3E%220%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22definite+integral%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22sqrt%28arcsin%28cos%28x%29%29*arctan%28cot%28x%29%29%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22DefiniteIntegralCalculator%22%2C+%22rangeend%22%7D+-%3E%22pi%22) may also help.

Comment: Anyway, this is not a proof.

Answer (score 2):

We must be careful with the domains.

- $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)=x$ ONLY when $x\in[0,\pi]$.
- $\cot^{-1}(\cot x)=x$ ONLY when $x\in[0,\pi]$.

So basically you have gotten lucky with the domain, as you are about to see.
$$\sin^{-1}(\cos x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos^{-1}(\cos x)= \frac{\pi}{2}- x$$
$$\tan^{-1}(\cot x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\cot^{-1}(\cot x)= \frac{\pi}{2}- x,$$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$, which is precisely the bounds of the integral. (If the bounds were outside $[0,\pi]$, then you might have had some problems.)

So you get the integral as $$\int_0^\pi\sqrt{\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^2}dx=\int_0^\pi\bigg|\frac{\pi}{2}-x\bigg|dx$$ which, as user @KamalSaleh points out, is the area of TWO congruent isosceles right triangles, and is equal to $\dfrac{\pi^2}{4}$.

---

P.S. Here are the graphs of $\cos^{-1}(\cos x)$ and $\cot^{-1}(\cot x)$ respectively for better understanding. [image]
[image]

Comment: Equivalently, of _one_ right-angled isosceles triangle, but with the "base" its hypotenuse.

Comment: Yeah. @J.G. I agree

Comment: @insipidintegrator Could you be more exact which problems are these: "(If the bounds were outside [0,π], then you might have had some problems.)" ? It's something with the sign ?

Comment: @user122424 they are not like, problems per se, just complications. Suppose the bounds were $\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\right]$ (half-in, half-out of $[0,\pi]$) then you would have to split the integral into half: $$\int_\tfrac{\pi}{2}^\tfrac{3\pi}{2}\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos x)\tan^{-1}(\cot x)}dx= \int_\tfrac{\pi}{2}^\pi\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos x)\tan^{-1}(\cot x)}dx+ \int_\pi^\tfrac{3\pi}{2}\sqrt{\sin^{-1}(\cos x)\tan^{-1}(\cot x)}dx$$$$= \int_\tfrac{\pi}{2}^\pi\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x\right)^2}dx+ \int_\pi^\tfrac{3\pi}{2}\sqrt{(x-\dfrac{3\pi}{2})(\frac{3\pi}{2}-x)}dx$$ (See graphs).

Comment: The second term is not defined as it’s a negative square. So the problem would have been unsolvable. If you draw the graph you’ll find that it is defined only in $(2n\pi, (2n+1)\pi)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @insipidintegrator It is not possible to integrate this $$\int_0^1\sqrt{-x}dx$$ by any means ?

Comment: In real calculus, no. The integrand is simply not defined, period. In complex analysis, maybe you can write it as $\displaystyle\int_0^1i\sqrt x dx$, but I don’t have sufficient background in complex analysis to assert that.